# How to click to one link in two tabs with selenium?

Tags: selenium

I am using C# in my tests. There is one link in two tabs. I see exception when I try to click on the 2nd tab`s link?

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//strong[contains(.,'Add All')]")]
        public IWebElement AddingButton;

  public void AddingNewTeam()
        {

              I.Click(LVElements.AddingButton);
              I.FillField(Name, NewTeamName);
              I.Click(AssigmentTab);
              I.Click(AddingButton);
              I.Click(RoleAssignment);
              **I.Click(AddingButton);**
              I.Click(ButtonSAVE);
        }
```

Comment: What type of exception is it? Can you paste the message?

Comment: @ElenaDyulgerska Update the question with relevant HTML of the element

Comment: <a data-bind="click: addAll"><strong style="margin-left: 5px;">Add All </strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a>     <strong style="margin-left: 5px;">Add All </strong>